# Regular expression for mobile number

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am trying to write regular expression for phone number which should accept 
input in following format 999-999-9999
apart from this it should not allow any other format 
i have tried

```
@"^[0-9-]*$"
```

Comment: Eh, `@"^[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}$"`? 3 digits - 3 digits - 4 digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (jQuery) {

    $("#<%=Phone.ClientID%>").change(function () {
        // alert('Value changed!');
        jQuery("input[id*=Phone]").mask("999-999-9999");
    });
```

this will automatically mask to you format

Answer (score 0):

Though i am not expert in either of your mentioned programming language but in python we can use "^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}$" and it will identify 999-999-999 only format. May be this will help!

Comment: `[0-9]` is a better choice for digit in the context, since `\d` allowes *all* possible digits e.g. eastern arabic ones, e.g. `١ ٢ ٣` for `123` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$
```

Answer (score 0):

Your desired regular Expression is   `^[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}$`